# String changing to "<" when added to my ndarray

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'm making a hangman game; this is /not/ a homework assignment, but more of an exploration/self-confidence in coding project (which is why I'm probably using a silly way to do this; I don't want to look at any tutorial for it).  I'm currently working on trying to build and print the "scaffold" that the guy hangs from.

I'm printing out an ndarray of (single char) strings but for some reason one character changes to "<" no matter what I put there.  Here's the code in the test I'm doing:

```
scaff_mat = np.full((10,20), ".", dtype=str)

scaff_mat[9,0] = "a"
scaff_mat[9,1] = "b"  # yes i know this will be replaced
scaff_mat[:, 1] = ("c" for i in scaff_mat)
```

Everything works except for "c" (or anything I put in its place) turns into "<".  (Debugging shows that it's not just changed when printing.)  I am aware that the list comprehension is probably wrong, so my question is both how do I do it right, and where on earth did the "<" come from?

Current output, for reference:

[image: output]

The ultimate goal would be a column of "|".

Comment: Hiya! Please [edit] your question to add your current output as text. You can use Control-K to make it look nice and pretty :)

Comment: Wild guess: the printable representation of `("c" for i in scaff_mat)` is `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03CBE1B0>`. The first character of that representation is "<". For some reason, this character and only this character is being written to the array. (posting as a comment and not an answer because I know nothing about numpy, and have no suggestions for how to actually fix the problem)

Comment: The problem is exactly that: when you put `("c" for i in scaff_mat)` you are actually making a generator. You can put `c` simply by assigning it to a slice `scaff_mat[:, 1] = 'c'` or building a list: `[] `instead of using `()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't do a list comprehension, but a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
scaff_mat = np.full((10,20), ".", dtype=str)

scaff_mat[9,0] = "a"
scaff_mat[9,1] = "b"  # yes i know this will be replaced
scaff_mat[:, 1] = ["c" for i in scaff_mat]
```

Change `(`&`)` to `[`&`]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ndarray` broadcasting:

```
scaff_mat[:, 1] = "c"
```